# How can I create such list in Haskell using list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

So I need to create such list

```
[2,4,5,8,9,10,11,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,32 ..]
```

The pattern goes as follows:
2^1,2^2, 2^2 +1, 2^3, 2^3 +1, 2^3 +2, 2^3 +3 .. So the number of repeats of (2^n +1, 2^n +2 .. is also doubling with each go ) I hope you got the point. 
I can create such list using functions in Haskell but I was interested whether or not it is possible to do it using solely list Comprehension

EDIT: Some people asked me to demonstrate a functional approach to this problem. Here it is

```
rep _ 0 = []
rep a b = a : rep (a+1) (b-1)
createlist a = rep (2^(a+1)) (2^a)  ++ createlist (a+1))
```

So if we say `take 50 (createlist 0) the results would be

```
[2,4,5,8,9,10,11,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82]
```

So you always need to call the function with initial parameter 0. It is really a nasty solution I would like to make it easier.

Comment: The pattern `2^0, 2^1, 2^1 +1, 2^2, 2^2 +1, 2^2 +2, 2^2 +3 .. ` would just create the list of positive integers. That does not match the list you showed above.

Comment: An attempt from your side? The specifications do not fully match the sample output.

Comment: Since you claim you can create such list, it would be interesting to share the code for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example, the list looks like:

```
 2
 4  5
 8  9 10 11
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 ...
```

So for every *i* from 1 to infinity, we yield the elements in the range *[2<sup>i</sup>,2<sup>i</sup>+2<sup>i-1</sup>)*. We can write this directly into  list comprehension:

```
[ j | i <- [1..], j <- [2^i .. 2^i + 2^(i-1) - 1] ]
```

We can also let `i` take powers of two, and yield elements between `i`, and `div (3*i) 2` (exclusive), so:

```
[ j | i <- iterate (2*) 2, j <- [i .. div (2*i) 3 - 1] ]
```

We can turn that also into a list monad, like:

```
iterate (*2) 2 >>= \i -> [i..div (3*i) 2 - 1]
```

or more point-free (and point-less):

```
import Control.Monad(ap)

iterate (*2) 2 >>= ap enumFromTo (pred . flip div 2 . (3 *))
```

Answer (score 0):

One could try to write the i*th* term of the list using a function *f*(*i*), where i >= 0

The overall infinite list can be represented as

`L_0 ++ L_1 ++ L_2 ++ ...`

where each L_n is a finite list of the form

`L_n = [ 2^(n+1), 2^(n+1) + 1, ..., 2^(n+1) + (2^n - 1) ]`

The size of L_n is 2^n and we know that for any k, 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^k = 2^(k+1) - 1 (it's a geometric progression) so if we're asked to find which finite list the i*th* term of the infinite list is in, we can find the highest integer m for which i >= 2^m - 1. Once that's done, we can safely say the i*th* term is in L_m. We can *also* say that the i*th* term of the infinite list is the (i - 2^m + 1)*th* element of L_m.

This allows us to define the final sequence (let's call it thatList) as

`thatList :: [Int]
 thatList = [ f i | i <- [0..] ]`

and

`f :: Int -> Int
 f i = (2 ^ (m + 1)) + (i - (2 ^ m) + 1)
         where
     m = floor (logBase 2 (fromIntegral i + 1))`